# Laying out a SWT component hierarchy

Tags: eclipse, swt

**What's the best way to cause a component hierarchy to relayout when a SWT control's preferred size changes?**  My particular situation is a dynamic update of a Label's text.

Comment: I'd love to see this question addressed to Swing and AWT controls as well.  Layouts are hard, and I've never found that one pattern that just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only approach I know of, suggested by bokowski as an answer to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586414/why-does-an-swt-composite-sometimes-require-a-call-to-resize-to-layout-correctl), is to walk up the component hierarchy to a Composite `ancestor` with scrollbars, then call `ancestor.layout(new Control[] { changedDescendent })`.  Is there a better way to do this?  Preferably with a simple method call on the changed control or its parent.